# If condition in PowerBi and excel

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have project where i need to show traffic lights condition ..

I  have to columns One is planned and one is Actual Status so

If status < 33% of planned status then red
If status >= 33 of planned and <66 then orange 
Else green

Comment: You do this with conditional formatting, not just a formula in the cell.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-conditional-table-formatting

Comment: I mean how do i know when planned 33% is and when 66% is i have to do manul